# Searching via $.getJSON not work?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have googling this issue but still not found the answer.

I try to create Seaching via Jquery JSON with getJSON method. this my code

> PHP file:
>   **report_cari.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "koneksi.php";
ini_set('display_errors', '0');


$sql = "SELECT RID,MESIN,DATE(HARI_TGL)AS TGL,TGL_REAL,PRODUK FROM adonan WHERE DATE(HARI_TGL) LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR PRODUK LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' GROUP BY RID ORDER BY TGL_REAL DESC";

$hasil = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$results = array();

foreach($hasil as $row){

     $results[] = array(
          'RID'=> $row[RID],
          'MESIN' => $row[MESIN],
          'TGL' => $row[TGL],
          'TGL_REAL' => $row[TGL_REAL],
          'PRODUK' => $row[PRODUK],
     );
}


$json = json_encode($results);

echo $json;
?>
```

> and javascipt: report.php

```
    <input id="CARILAH" data-type="search">


<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: auto">
        <table data-role="table" id="tabel1" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive" data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Columns to display..." 
        data-column-popup-theme="a" data-input="#filterTable-input">
         <thead>
           <tr class="ui-bar-d">
             <th data-priority="1" align='center'>RID</th>
             <th data-priority="1" align='center'>MESIN</th>
             <th data-priority="1" align='center'>TGL</th>
             <th data-priority="1" align='center'>WAKTU</th>
             <th data-priority="1" align='center'>PRODUK</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <!--div id='records_table'></div-->
         </tbody>
         </table>
</div>
```

> javascript

```
 <script src="jqm2/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm2/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

/*for view data*/
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "report_action.php",
      dataType: "json",

     success: function (response) {

        // alert(JSON.stringify(response));

        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {

            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.RID + '</td><td>' + item.MESIN + '</td><td>' + item.TGL + '</td><td>' + item.TGL_REAL + '</td><td><a href="report_detail.php?RID='+ item.RID +'" data-ajax="false" target="_parent">' + item.PRODUK + '</a></td></tr>';     
        });
        $('#tabel1 tbody').append(trHTML);
    },



});


   /*for searching data*/
   $("#CARILAH").keyup(function(){
      var oke = $(this).val();

          //alert(oke);
          $.getJSON("report_cari.php", function(result){

                 if (!json[0]) {
                    //console.log("NO DATA!")
                    alert("tidak ada data");
                 }          
                 else{
                         var trHTML = '';
                      $.each(response, function (i, item) {

                      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.RID + '</td><td>' + item.MESIN + '</td><td>' + item.TGL + '</td><td>' + item.TGL_REAL + '</td><td><a href="report_detail.php?RID='+ item.RID +'" data-ajax="false" target="_parent">' + item.PRODUK + '</a></td></tr>';       
                     });
                    $('#tabel1 tbody').append(trHTML); 

                 }               


          });

     });

});
</script>
```

this file is combine ajax for search and for View data.
but not work.
View data Work. Search data not work. How can I get data From json_encode with $getJSON keyup event?

> nb: report_cari.php work and can generate JSON.

Anyone can help?

thanks in advance.

Comment: is this JS file on the same level as "report_cari.php"?..seems like the URL issue.

Comment: Js file is same place with report.php

Comment: check the call in your browser console..it should show you something,

Comment: @tachie_28, console show json is not defined, but if I run report_cari.php?term=2016 it work [{"RID":"D51390","MESIN":"","TGL":"2016-03-28","TGL_REAL":"10:00:00","PRODUK":"Montego Chocolate Choco Chips 50 g"},{"RID":"A72951","MESIN":"M3","TGL":"2016-03-28","TGL_REAL":"09:30:00","PRODUK":"Litelmaxx Cheese 45 gr"}]

Comment: It could be referring to the json array in your callback..you are expecting it in result var but using json[0].. should it be result[0]?

Comment: What is your expected result here `if (!json[0])` ? Because this is the result of your JSON `'RID'=> $row[RID],
          'MESIN' => $row[MESIN],
          'TGL' => $row[TGL],
          'TGL_REAL' => $row[TGL_REAL],
          'PRODUK' => $row[PRODUK]` which key here is you mean in your `[0]` index value in JSON. You mean `RID`? Does it boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send searched parameter to server like below, [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) have optional parameter data

```
$("#CARILAH").keyup(function(){
      var oke = $(this).val();

          $.getJSON("report_cari.php",{term : oke}, function(result){

                 if (result.length == 0) {
                    console.log("NO DATA!")

                 }          
                 else{
                         var trHTML = '';
                      $.each(result, function (i, item) {

                      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.RID + '</td><td>' + item.MESIN + '</td><td>' + item.TGL + '</td><td>' + item.TGL_REAL + '</td><td><a href="report_detail.php?RID='+ item.RID +'" data-ajax="false" target="_parent">' + item.PRODUK + '</a></td></tr>';       
                     });
                    $('#tabel1 tbody').append(trHTML); 

                 }               


          });

     });
```

Comment: i have try your advice but still not work. console result ReferenceError: response is not defined, is my code crash with other jquery?

Comment: If you are using response as variable then also change it in function(response) in getJSON

Comment: Can you edit your answer, because I still not understand.

Comment: can you please replace your search code with the above code

Comment: i have replace it with your advice. yeah it append data on keyup, but it not back when I remove my keyword. How can I do that?

Comment: use `$("#yourtbodyid").empty();`  inside your keyup function

Comment: Welcome.Happy coding !